# Nginx check multiple roots

Tags: nginx

I have a location in my `nginx` configuration :

```
   location ~ \.(js|jpg|png|css|gif|ico|svg|jpeg)$ {
            root /some/basic/root;
       }
```

It works for static files in one directory `/some/basic/root`. But I have some other static files like `css` and `js` in other directories :

`root /completely/other/root`;

`root /completely/other/root/dir1`;

`root /completely/other/root/dir2`;

How to make `nginx` check also other directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a common parent directory, you can use `try_files` to test each subdirectory in turn:

```
location ~ \.(js|css)$ {
    root /common/parent;
    try_files /basic/root$uri /other/root$uri /other/root/dir1$uri /other/root/dir2$uri =404;
}
```

If a common parent directory is not practical, you can cascade `location` blocks, again using `try_files`:

```
location ~ \.(js|css)$ {
    root /some/basic/root;
    try_files $uri @other;
}
location @other {
    root /completely/other/root;
    try_files $uri /dir1$uri /dir2$uri =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.